# How to compare compare contour of two image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have stored the area of all contours in a vector for first frame and now I want to compare area of each contour for second frame with first frame. If there area are same they put in a vector and if they are not same they put in another vector. how can I do it? Please help me.
Thanks in advance

```
// one frame at a time

void draw_ellipse(Mat &a,int count)

{ 

     findContours( th1, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE,
                    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0) ); 

      for(i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
       {
          area.push_back(contourArea(contours[i]));// area is a vector
       }

      for(j=1;j<=count;j++)
       {

         for(i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
          {

            if(area[i]>area[i+1])         // v1,v2,v3 are vectors
               v1.push_back(contours[i]);

            else if(area[i]<area[i+1])
               v2.push_back(contours[i]);

            else if(area[i]==area[i+1])
               v3.push_back(contours[i]);
          }

       }

    }
```

Now this function compares contours within same frame but I want that second frame's each contour compare with each contour of 1st frame then it should go in different vectors.

Comment: It looks like simple comparison, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Actually I am unable to compare each contour for second frame with all contours of first frame because in a function all the things have been done according to first frame like conditions..but when 2nd frame come it will also meet the same conditions and function process each frame at a time..

Comment: @Tyro: contour comparison isn't simple at all.

Comment: Are you trying to match certain point of first frame and second frame?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust, yes, I got that now. Question was only first three lines when I commented. It has been edited after that. It is definitely not simple.

Comment: all the contours of 1st frame should be matched to all contours of 2nd frame

Comment: Yes, I am facing this problem. So, overall problem is that I have a number of frames and I have taken the contours of all the frame. now, I want to cluster those contour according to their area and angle. That means, If one frame comes then parameters will be calculated and cluster will be made, whenever another frame appears then all the contour of this frame should be matched to previous frame's contours. How will I do that? Any suggestion would be helpful, please!!

Comment: matching features may be feasible solution to the problem ! Feature matching example -> http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html ! There is a contour matching method in python you can check this example in python -> http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#contours-more-functions

Answer (score 0):

There are pre defined functions in OpenCV to match contours [Opencv Contour Matching C++](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contour#double%20matchShapes%28InputArray%20contour1,%20InputArray%20contour2,%20int%20method,%20double%20parameter%29)